# How to enable button when checkbox clicked in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to enable button when checkbox clicked in jQuery?

Comment: Show some effort here and post your code. Otherwise close.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#checkBoxID").click(function() {
  $("#buttonID").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

This enables when checked, and disables again if you uncheck.  In jQuery `.attr("disabled", bool)` takes a boolean, so you can keep this pretty short using the `this.checked` DOM property of the checkbox.

Comment: +1 for the negating the boolean, it's a simple technique that isn't used enough, IMO. Oh, and not using *.is(":checked")*, too ;-)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6 it's recommended to use the .prop() method for this instead (http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#yourcheckboxid").click(function() {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    if (checked_status == true) {
       $("#yourbuttonid").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
       $("#yourbuttonid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using Bootstrap with Jquery, "disabled" is not an attribute but a class. So, (and I usually keep my functions on a separate loadable file to keep it clean) do this:

1. Create whatever.js
2. Put this code in it:

   function seethemagic(){
   $('#btn-send').toggleClass('disabled');
   }
3. Load whatever.js into your html
4. The button can look like this:

   `<button id="btn-send" class="btn btn-primary d-grid w-100 disabled"` `onclick="seethemagic();">Show me the magic</button>`

This way the button will toggle on and off.