# enable/diable submit with checkbox on page load

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, controls

So I am trying to enable or disable a submit button when a checkbox is check or unchecked respectively.  **The checkbox by default is unchecked *on Page Load*, however the Submit button is enabled.**  Here is my code:

**The script:**

```
<script>

EnableSubmit = function(val)
 {
var sbmt = document.getElementById("submit");

if (val.checked == true)
{
    sbmt.disabled = false;
}
else
{
    sbmt.disabled = true;
}
}  
</script>
```

**The HMTL:**

```
<input name="agree" type="checkbox" class="equipmentTroubleForm"  onClick="EnableSubmit(this)" value="Accept">
```

Comment: Firstly, thats not `jQuery` that is `Javascript`

Comment: You can use something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565632/how-to-enable-button-when-checkbox-clicked-in-jquery) if you **are** using `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your function is called only when you click your checkbox. Try:

```
<script>

EnableSubmit = function(val)
 {
var sbmt = document.getElementById("submit");

if (val.checked == true)
{
    sbmt.disabled = false;
}
else
{
    sbmt.disabled = true;
}
}  
EnableSubmit({checked:false});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only making this check when the checkbox is clicked, you need to also do it on page load.

To prevent any errors though, you can pass an object that has a falsy `checked` property:

```
EnableSubmit({checked:0});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm34z34q/)

Or you could simply give your `<input>` the `disabled` attribute, meaning it will always be disabled by default on page load:

```
<input type='submit' id='submit' disabled >
```

If, like your tags suggest, you are using jQuery, this snippet will suffice:

```
// Attach an event handler
$('.equipmentTroubleForm').click(function(){

    // Set the disabled property to the opposite of this.checked
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', !this.checked);

// Trigger the click (and functionality) on page load 
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

More easy, you need the value of the check and put as value of the form.disable.

Example

```
var check = document.getElementById('ID_CHECK_BOX').value;
document.getElementById("submit").disable = check;
```

And call this function on-click in the check button.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Check the demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1svd0vx/).
So, all you have to do is to make event handler that checks the state of checkbox at the moment of submit. Here it is:

**JS**:

```
function addEvent(elem, type, handler){ // kinda cross browser event attachment
  if (elem.addEventListener){
    elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false)
   } else {
    elem.attachEvent("on"+type, function() { handler.call(elem) })
  }
}
var checkbox = document.getElementById('FormControl');
var form = document.getElementById('DataForm');
addEvent(form, 'submit', function(e) {
     if(checkbox.checked) { 
         console.log('Cancel submit');
         e.preventDefault();
         //window.history.back();
         console.log(window.history);
         return;
     }
     else {
          console.log('Proceed submit');
     }
});
```

And a sample **HTML**:

```
<input name="agree" type="checkbox" class="equipmentTroubleForm" value="Accept" id="FormControl">
<form id="DataForm" method='GET' action='/'>
     <input type="text" name="test">
     <input type="submit">     
</form>
```

Pay attention to the commented string with `window.history.back()`. Form may not be submitted, but browser may think it was, so if you care about user's history uncomment it and double check if history's state is fine. Good luck!