# how to change attribute "hidden" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" name="del_attachment_id[]" value="<?php echo $attachment['link'];?>">
</td>

<td id="delete" hidden="true">
the file will be deleted from the newsletter
</td>
```

I want to know how can i change the attribute "hidden" to false in Jquery when the checkbox is checked or not checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable button when checkbox clicked in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565632/how-to-enable-button-when-checkbox-clicked-in-jquery)

Comment: @user3314813, if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: Using .prop('hidden', false) and .prop('hidden', true) worked for me while .removeAttr('hidden') didn't.

Answer (score 68):

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#delete').removeAttr('hidden');
});
```

Note, thanks to tip by `A.Wolff`, you should use `removeAttr` instead of setting to false. When set to false, the element will still be hidden. Therefore, removing is more effective.

Comment: Hidden is a boolean attribute, you need to remove it, not setting it to `'false'`. Or use `.prop('hidden', false);`

Comment: @A.Wolff, do you mean attr wont work or something else?

Comment: @A.Wolff, according to http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/hidden-html-attribute/ value is 'true' or 'false'

Comment: Looks like wrong interpretation,see e.g setting it to false, element still hidden: https://jsfiddle.net/nyq35m7x/

Comment: @A.Wolff, I see. Thanks so much for pointing out. Updated my answer giving you credit. :) thanks again

Answer (score 66):

You can use jquery attr method

```
$("#delete").attr("hidden",true);
```

Comment: Put the change handler in your answer so it will be complete answer. Then, I will delete mine

Comment: why not `.prop("hidden",true);`?

Comment: @Alex78191 `hidden` is an attribute, not a property. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hidden.asp

Comment: there is a `hidden` property https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden

Answer (score 17):

A. Wolff was leading you in the right direction. There are several attributes where you should not be setting a string value. You must toggle it with a boolean `true` or `false`.

`.attr("hidden", false)` will remove the attribute the same as using `.removeAttr("hidden")`.

`.attr("hidden", "false")` is incorrect and the tag remains hidden.

You should not be setting `hidden`, `checked`, `selected`, or several others to any string value to toggle it.

Answer (score 12):

Use **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** for updating the hidden property, and **[`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** for handling the change event.

```js
$('#check').change(function() {
  $("#delete").prop("hidden", !this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="del_attachment_id[]" value="<?php echo $attachment['link'];?>">
    </td>

    <td id="delete" hidden="true">
      the file will be deleted from the newsletter
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```